# TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have developed my own photobooth software using a Raspberry Pi and a DSLR cam, as well as Python, TkInter and gPhoto library. The photobooth software is pretty flexible, because of using a config file and supports serveral types of input buttons and leds as well as live preview and random photo gallery (as a screensaver). I am also able to manipulate camera settings for live preview and taking the final photo.

Most of the time the software runs quite stable. But somethings (mostly once at an evening) I get an unhandled exception which I am not able to fix and the photobooth software needs to be restarted manually. The unhandled exception appears after taking a final photo. Due to the fact that the unhandled exception appears randomly I am not able to reproduce it on my own.

The unhandled exception is always the same:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/pi/photoBooth/scripts/photoBoothGUI.pyw", line 476, in main
>      try: ThreadedClient(Tk()).start()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1823, in **init**
>      self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>
> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

As a quick'n'dirty solution I already tried to put most of the function calls which could possibly throw an exception inside a try-and-catch-block. But that did not fix the exception above.

Here is the code of photoBoothGui.pyw:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Imports
import Queue, threading
import sys, os, traceback
import time, datetime, random

from gPhotoWrapper import GPhotoWrapper
from photoUtils import PhotoUtils

from RPi import GPIO
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, BOTH, Button, CENTER
from tkFont import Font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps
from configparser import ConfigParser
from enum import Enum
from shutil import copyfile


#Class Definitions

class MessageType(Enum):
    IMAGE = 0
    TEXT = 1
    IMAGE_TEXT = 2

class Message():

    def __init__(self, mType, text = None, fontSize=None, image=None):
        self.mType = mType
        self.text = text
        self.fontSize = fontSize
        self.image = image

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, queue, config):

        #Init root window and root queue
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = queue

        #Configure font
        self.labelFont = Font(family=config.get('Font','Family'), size=config.get('Font','SizeTitle'))
        self.labelFont.configure(weight='bold') if config.getboolean('Font','Bold') else None

        #Configure main label    
        self.mainLabel = Label(self, compound=CENTER, font=self.labelFont, text=config.get('RootWindow','AppTitle'), wraplength=1280)
        self.mainLabel.configure(background=config.get('RootWindow','BackgroundColor'))
        self.mainLabel.configure(foreground=config.get('RootWindow','ForegroundColor'))
        self.mainLabel.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        #Configure root window
        self.parent.title(config.get('RootWindow','AppTitle'))
        self.parent.attributes('-fullscreen', config.getboolean('RootWindow','Fullscreen'))
        self.config(cursor='none')


    def processIncoming(self):

        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(0)
                if msg.mType == MessageType.TEXT:
                    self.showText(msg.text, msg.fontSize)
                    self.resetImage()
                elif msg.mType == MessageType.IMAGE:
                    self.showImage(msg.image)
                    self.resetText()
                elif msg.mType == MessageType.IMAGE_TEXT:
                    self.showImage(msg.image)
                    self.showText(msg.text, msg.fontSize)
                else:
                    print('Message Type "' + str(msg.mType) + '" not implemented, yet')
            except:
                pass

    def showImage(self, img):
        try:
            photoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            self.mainLabel.configure(image = photoImage)
            self.mainLabel.image = photoImage
        except:
            pass

    def showText(self, textToShow, fontSize):
        try:
            self.mainLabel.configure(text=textToShow)
            self.labelFont.configure(size=fontSize)
        except:
            pass

    def resetImage(self):
        self.mainLabel.configure(image='')

    def resetText(self):
        self.mainLabel.configure(text='')

    def getMaxImageWidth(self):
        return self.mainLabel.winfo_width();

    def getMaxImageHeight(self):
        return self.mainLabel.winfo_height();

class ClientState(Enum):
    BUSY = 0
    READY_CAPTURE = 1

class ThreadedClient:

    def __init__(self,window):

        #Save a reference to root window
        self.window = window

        #Init config object
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        try:
            if not self.config.read(sys.argv[1]):
                raise IOError('File "' + sys.argv[1] + '" not found!') 
        except IndexError, IOError:
            if not self.config.read(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]+'.config'):
                print('Loading config file failed.')
                sys.exit()

        #Setup GPhoto Wrapper
        self.photoWrapper = GPhotoWrapper()

        #Setup photo utils
        self.photoUtils = PhotoUtils()

        #Create queue
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()

        #Setup the GUI
        self.gui = GUI(window, self.queue , self.config)

        #Bind keypress event to GUI
        self.gui.parent.bind("<Return>", self.readKeypressCapture)

        #Start periodic call in GUI
        self.periodicCall(self.config.getint('RootWindow','UpdateIntervall'))

        #Setup the GPIO 
        self.setupGPIO()

        #Setup Slideshow thread
        self.setupThreads()

        #Set the application to be ready for taking the first photo
        self.setClientState(ClientState.READY_CAPTURE)

    def start(self):
        self.window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close)
        self.window.mainloop()

    def close(self):

        #Cancel background thread
        self.threadSlideshow.cancel()

        #Reset GPIO pins
        GPIO.cleanup()

        #Close GUI
        self.window.destroy()

    def setClientState(self, clientState):
        self.state = clientState

    def periodicCall(self, intervall):

        #Process incoming queue messages
        self.gui.processIncoming()

        #Restart periodic call every x ms
        self.window.after(intervall, self.periodicCall, intervall)

    def setupGPIO(self):

        #Setup GPIO pin layout
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        bounceTime = self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','Bouncetime')

        #Capturing: Setup GPIO pins and wait for capture events
        GPIO.setup(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','ButtonCaptureGPIO'), GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','ButtonCaptureGPIO'), GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.readButtonCapture, bouncetime=bounceTime)

        if self.config.getboolean('RPi GPIO','EnableRadioCapture'):
            GPIO.setup(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','ButtonCaptureRadioGPIO'), GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
            GPIO.add_event_detect(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','ButtonCaptureRadioGPIO'), GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.readButtonCapture, bouncetime=bounceTime)

        #LED: Setup GPIO pin and initialize LED status to high signal
        if self.config.getboolean('RPi GPIO','EnableCaptureLED'):
            GPIO.setup(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','LedCaptureGPIO'), GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','LedCaptureGPIO'), GPIO.HIGH)

    def setupThreads(self):

        if self.config.getboolean('Slideshow','EnableSlideshow'):
            self.threadSlideshow = RepeatingTimer(interval=self.config.getint('Slideshow','DisplayDuration'), target=self.showRandomImage)
        else:
            self.threadSlideshow = RepeatingTimer(interval=self.config.getint('Slideshow','DisplayDuration'), target=self.dummy)

    def readButtonCapture(self, channel):
        threading.Thread(target=self.captureImageButtonThread, args=[channel]).start()

    def readKeypressCapture(self, key):
        threading.Thread(target=self.captureImageThread).start()

    def captureImageButtonThread(self, channel):

        try:

            #Check the button to be pressed curtain amount of time 
            timeThreshold = time.time() + (self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','Threshold')/1000)
            while timeThreshold > time.time():
                if GPIO.input(channel): return

            self.captureImageThread()

        except:

            #Show Error Message
            self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamFailed'), fontSize=self.config.getint('Font','SizeMessage')))

    def captureImageThread(self):

        if self.state == ClientState.BUSY: return

        try:

            #Stop background threads (LED and Slideshow)
            self.threadSlideshow.cancel()
            if self.config.getboolean('RPi GPIO','EnableCaptureLED'):
                GPIO.output(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','LedCaptureGPIO'), GPIO.LOW)

            #Capture image
            self.captureImage()

            #Restart background threads (LED and Slideshow)
            self.threadSlideshow.startAfter(self.config.getint('Slideshow','StartTime'))
            if self.config.getboolean('RPi GPIO','EnableCaptureLED'):
                GPIO.output(self.config.getint('RPi GPIO','LedCaptureGPIO'), GPIO.HIGH)

        except:

            #Show Error Message
            self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamFailed'), fontSize=self.config.getint('Font','SizeMessage')))

    def captureImage(self):

        #Check whether application is ready to capture new image
        if self.state == ClientState.BUSY: return

        #Switch applications' state
        self.setClientState(ClientState.BUSY)

        #Read config values for capture mode
        fontSizeMessage = self.config.getint('Font','SizeMessage')
        fontSizeCountdown = self.config.getint('Font','SizeCountdown')
        isLivePreview = self.config.getboolean('GPhotoParameter','LivePreview')

        #Establish connection to camera
        if self.photoWrapper.connect():

            #Start live preview
            if isLivePreview:
                isoKey = self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','IsoSpeed')
                isoValuePrev = self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','IsoSpeedValuePreview')
                apertureKey = self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','Aperture')
                apertureValuePrev = self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','ApertureValuePreview')
                apertureValueCapt = isoValueCapt = None

                if self.config.getboolean('GPhotoParameter','FixCaptureSettings'):
                    apertureValueCapt = self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','ApertureValueCapture')
                    isoValueCapt = self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','IsoSpeedValueCapture')

                if not self.photoWrapper.startPreview(isoKey, isoValuePrev, isoValueCapt, apertureKey, apertureValuePrev, apertureValueCapt):

                    #Close connection to camera
                    self.photoWrapper.disconnect()

                    #Show Error Message
                    self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamNotReady'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))

                    #Switch applications' state
                    self.setClientState(ClientState.READY_CAPTURE)

                    return

            #Start countdown for posing
            countdown = self.config.getfloat('Photos','Countdown')
            stepSize = self.config.getfloat('RootWindow','UpdateIntervall')/1000

            while countdown > 0:
                number = int(countdown)
                textMsg = number if number>0 else self.config.get('Text','CamPhotoShot')
                textSize = fontSizeCountdown if number>0 else fontSizeMessage
                if isLivePreview:
                        prevImage = self.photoWrapper.capturePreview()
                        if prevImage != False: self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.IMAGE_TEXT, text=textMsg, fontSize=textSize, image=ImageOps.mirror(prevImage)))
                        else: self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=textMsg, fontSize=textSize))
                else: self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=textMsg, fontSize=textSize))
                countdown -= stepSize
                time.sleep(stepSize)

            #Stop live preview
            if not self.photoWrapper.stopPreview():

                #Close connection to camera
                self.photoWrapper.disconnect()

                #Show Error Message
                self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamNotReady'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))

                #Switch applications' state
                self.setClientState(ClientState.READY_CAPTURE)

                return

            #Capture image
            camFilePath = self.photoWrapper.captureImage()
            if camFilePath:

                #Download image
                self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamPhotoDownload'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))
                try:
                    unixTimeStamp = self.photoWrapper.getConfigValue(self.config.get('GPhotoParameter','CameraDateTime'))
                    localFilePath = os.path.join(self.config.get('Photos','PathLocal'), self.fileName(unixTimeStamp))
                except:
                    localFilePath = None

                if (localFilePath and self.photoWrapper.downloadImage(camFilePath,localFilePath)):

                    try:

                        #Process image
                        self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamPhotoProcessing'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))
                        origImage = Image.open(localFilePath)

                        #Resize image in two steps (best trade-off between speed and quality)
                        scaledImage = self.photoUtils.resizeAspectRatio(origImage, self.gui.getMaxImageHeight())
                        previewImage = scaledImage.copy()

                        #Save (resized) image to webservers' photo directory
                        if self.config.getboolean('Photos','CopyToWebServer'):
                            self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamPhotoSave'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))
                            targetOrig = os.path.join(self.config.get('Photos','PathWebServerOrig'), os.path.basename(localFilePath))
                            targetThumb = os.path.join(self.config.get('Photos','PathWebServerThumb'), os.path.basename(localFilePath))
                            if self.config.getboolean('Photos','SaveScaledImage'):
                                scaledImage = self.photoUtils.resizeFixed(origImage, self.config.getint('Photos','OrigHeight'), self.config.getint('Photos','OrigWidth'))
                                scaledImage.save(targetOrig, quality=self.config.getint('Photos','OrigQuality'))
                            else: copyfile(localFilePath, targetOrig)
                            scaledImage = self.photoUtils.resizeFixed(scaledImage, self.config.getint('Photos','ThumbHeight'), self.config.getint('Photos','ThumbWidth'))
                            scaledImage.save(targetThumb)

                        #Show image
                        self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.IMAGE, image=previewImage))

                    except:

                        self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamPhotoProcessFailed'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))

                else: self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamPhotoDownloadFailed'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))
            else: self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamNotReady'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))
        else: self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','CamNotDetected'), fontSize=fontSizeMessage))

        #Close connection to camera
        self.photoWrapper.disconnect()

        #Switch applications' state
        self.setClientState(ClientState.READY_CAPTURE)

    def showRandomImage(self):

        #Check client state
        if self.state == ClientState.BUSY: return False
        self.setClientState(ClientState.BUSY)

        #Show loading message
        self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('Text','PleaseWait'), fontSize=self.config.get('Font','SizeMessage')))

        #Get random image from slideshow directory
        if (self.config.getboolean('Slideshow','EnableAdvertisements')):
            if(random.randint(0,3) > 0):
                filePath = self.config.get('Slideshow','SlideShowFolder')
            else:
                filePath = self.config.get('Slideshow','AdvertisementFolder')
        else:
            filePath = self.config.get('Slideshow','SlideShowFolder')

        if os.listdir(filePath):

            try:

                fileName = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(filePath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(filePath, x))])
                filePathAndName = os.path.join(filePath, fileName)

                #Resize image in two steps (best trade-off between speed and quality)
                scaledImage = self.photoUtils.resizeAspectRatio(Image.open(filePathAndName), self.gui.getMaxImageHeight())

                #Show Image
                self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.IMAGE, image=scaledImage))

            except:

                self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('RootWindow','AppTitle'), fontSize=self.config.get('Font','SizeTitle')))

        #Change Client State
        self.setClientState(ClientState.READY_CAPTURE)

        return True

    def reset(self):
        if not self.state == ClientState.READY_CAPTURE: return
        self.queue.put(Message(mType=MessageType.TEXT, text=self.config.get('RootWindow','AppTitle'), fontSize=self.config.get('Font','SizeTitle')))

    def fileName(self, unixTimeStamp):
        prefix = self.config.get('Photos','Prefix')
        return prefix + time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S', time.localtime(unixTimeStamp)) + '.jpg'

    def dummy():
        return False

class RepeatingTimer(object):

    def __init__(self, interval, target, onCancel=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.interval = interval
        self.target = target
        self.onCancel = onCancel
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.timer = None
        self.isAlive = False

    def callback(self):
        if self.target(*self.args, **self.kwargs):
            self.isAlive = False
            self.startAfter(self.interval)
        else: self.isAlive = False

    def cancel(self):
        self.isAlive = False
        if not self.timer == None: self.timer.cancel()
        if not self.onCancel == None: self.onCancel(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        self.startAfter(self.interval)

    def startAfter(self, interval):
        if self.isAlive: return
        self.timer = threading.Timer(interval, self.callback)
        self.isAlive = True
        self.timer.start()

class Logger(file):

    def __init__(self, name, mode = 'w'):
        self = file.__init__(self, name, mode)

    def writeLine(self, string):
        self.writelines(string + '\n')
        return None

#Main Function

def main():

    while(True):

        try: ThreadedClient(Tk()).start()

        except:

            #Get information from unhandled exception
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            exceptionInfo = repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,exc_traceback))

            #Output unhandled exception to error.log file
            f = Logger(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+'/errors.log','a')
            f.writeLine('')
            f.writeLine('***************************************************')
            f.writeLine('**                   EXCEPTION                   **')
            f.writeLine('***************************************************')
            for line in traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,exc_traceback): f.writeLine(line)
            f.close()

        else: break

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    main()
```

Would be great to get some hints how to fix the unhandled exception.

Comment: it seems your host system does not have a display or display variable set. try ` echo $DISPLAY
`
it should response `:0` or something similar, try exporting your display device from a host. 

    export DISPLAY=:0

Comment: @parthvadhadiya i m also facing same issue. I have jenkins on a linux server as slave. Where I need to add this line export DISPLAY=:0. I am not able to find any properties file of jenkins on linux server.

Comment: @RishiBansal hi can you please share output of this command `echo $DISPLAY `

Comment: @parthvadhadiya thanks for reply, I used matplotlib background "matplotlib.use('Agg')" for this as there was no need of active display.